# How do I fix ERROR: No signature of method: build_736eq4o62b75hodqgip5fud2k.android()

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:...\QRTic\QRTic_Customer\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 34
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_736eq4o62b75hodqgip5fud2k.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_736eq4o62b75hodqgip5fud2k$_run_closure3) values: [build_736eq4o62b75hodqgip5fud2k$_run_closure3@389d26e3]

The build gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_application_1"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs{
        debug{
            keyAlias 'qrtic'
            storePassword '123456'
            storeFile file('qrtic.jks')
            keypassword '123456'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what causes the error, what do I need to fix?

Comment: Android block is being called as a method, but it is not defined as one, could be caused by a typo in the build.gradle file, or it could be caused by an issue with the build script itself. It's worth checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this error?

```
unable to resolve class GradleException @ line 11, column 15.Gradle
```

Code where an error appears:

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk') 
if (flutterRoot == null) { 
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.") 
}
```

I don't think this should be the main cause.

[image]